# Vim split bar styling

Tags: vim

How do I style or remove the grey bar that appears on window split?

[image]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You'll need to edit your colorscheme. The highlight group is `VertSplit`.

If you want to get rid of the pipe characters you can set `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` to the same value.

#### Additional information on styling vertical split borders*:

*Taken from ib. answer below.

In order to get rid of | characters, one should rather change vertical separator using:

```
:set fillchars+=vert:\
```

(note the significant whitespace after the '\' character)

Comment: Actually, in order to get rid of `|` characters, one should rather change vertical separator using `:set fillchars+=vert:\ `, than make background and foreground colors be equal (which is fine as workaround, but not as straightforward solution).

Comment: Thank you, I think I've used it previously but ultimately removed it in an attempt to clean up my .vimrc. Completely forgot about it. Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: @romainl:  Suggestion on changing the vertical separator character does not answer the question about styling of vertical window borders completely.  Either your answer (mentioning `VertSplit`) with my comment (about `fillchars`) does it, or, the other way around, my answer with your comment.  So, there is no reason to increase entropy.  Also, it is already accepted anyway.

Comment: Now it's a complete answer.  I almost miss the comments! :)

Comment: What's the bottom bar's name in vim theme? In this question which shows [No Name] blablabla on it. I'd like to change color of that and can't find it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Zen, it's statusline.

Comment: Is it possible to *remove* (not make it look transparent) the separator? It is another precious character that I want to save up for my code.

Comment: btw, I like `set fillchars+=vert:\▏` as vertical bar

Comment: I just used `⡁` as vert ;)

Answer (score 17):

```
highlight VertSplit cterm=NONE
```

Answer (score 9):

I kind of tweak it a little to make it look like there is no splitbar with something like this

```
hi LineNr guibg=bg
set foldcolumn=2
hi foldcolumn guibg=bg
hi VertSplit guibg=bg guifg=bg
```

Note that I'm using gvim so I'm using guibg to change the background guifg to change the foreground with the same color of my vim's background, if you're not using a gui and you're on terminal vim you should change the `guibg` and `guifg` parameters for `ctermbg` and `ctermfg`

Comment: I get a BG not defined on some themes, what can I do?

Comment: Try to use your gui settings on a different file named ~/.gvimrc

Answer (score 0):

If you add a comment with `"` after the whitespace, you don't have a trailing white space. I don't like these, so my vim config shows them (vim-airline plugin) and I remove them regularly.

`:set fillchars+=vert:\ "White space at the end`